# CFML within Javascript

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, cfml

I am working on code written by someone else. To my knowledge its not correct but I am not seeing any errors and so now I am not sure if something changed since version 8.

The code is as below & I want to know if you can use CFML with Javascript code

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript" > 
    var x = 2;
    <cfif url.new = true>var x = 5 </cfif>
</script>
```

Comment: `<cfif url.new = true>var x = 5 </cfif>` Wrong syntax.   Use
`<cfif url.new eq true>var x = 5 </cfif>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use CFML within JavaScript per-se because ColdFusion runs on a server and JavaScript runs on the client. However, you need to consider how CFML works, the CFML code is *processed* on the server and then the output is passed on to the client. So in your case, the example that you provided is valid. The CFML will be processed on the server and one of two outputs will be generated and passed back to the client.

NOTE: You haven not included all of the code so I am assuming that there is additional code before this that checks for the existence of the `url.new` variable. Otherwise if the `new` argument is not passed in the URL then an error will be thrown that the variable does not exist.

If the URL does not contain an argument named "new"; http://www.yourdomain.com/somepage
or the "new" argument does exist but it's value is not considered to be "true"; http://www.yourdomain.com/somepage?new=false
then the output will be:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript" > 
    var x = 2;
</script>
```

Note that the value of "x" in the generated JavaScript will be 2.

If the URL does contain an argument named "new" and it's value is considered to be "true"; http://www.yourdomain.com/somepage?new=true
then the output will be:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript" > 
    var x = 2;
    var x = 5 
</script>
```

Note that the value of "x" in the generated JavaScript will be 5, however there is also a missing semi-colon at the end of the line so your example may throw a JavaScript error.

Notice that I also mention "if the value is considered to be true or false". In ColdFusion, Boolean expressions, True, nonzero numbers, and the strings "Yes", "1|", "True" are equivalent; and False, 0, and the strings "No", "0", and "False" are equivalent. Boolean evaluation is not case-sensitive. For example, True, TRUE, and true are equivalent. So in your example, http://www.yourdomain.com/somepage?new=1 would also be considered true.

Answer (score 3):

Well: you're not really using "CFML with Javascript code" in the way you're suggesting. What you have is some text, and CFML happens to be (conditionally) generating some other text.

The text it generates is going to be one of:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript" > 
    var x = 2;
    var x = 5 
</script>
```

Or

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript" > 
    var x = 2;

</script>
```

Depending on the value `URL.new`. Either way, it's all just text at the point the CFML server has any input into it.

That text then gets sent back to the web server, which sends it back to the browser which requested it. The browser then interprets the text as HTML, and within the HTML is some text which it's been told to treat as JavaScript. And so it does do (treats it as JavaScript, and runs it).

But this is long since the CFML server has had anything to do with it. All the CFML server does it churn out text.

This might help your understanding of the request/response lifecycle vis-a-vis a CFML server: "[The CFML request/response process](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/10/the-coldfusion-requestresponse-process.html)"

Comment: upvoted for the blog article link explaining the application server paradigm

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I can see wrong with your code here - this is what I would have there instead:

```
<script> 
    var x = 2;
    <cfif structKeyExists(URL, "new") AND URL.new IS true>x = 5;</cfif>
</script>
```

1. I've added a check to see if the variable 'new' exists in the URL scope - just in case you hadn't done it anywhere else.
2. If your CFIF statement you use = when you should be using EQ or IS. I don't know why CFIF logic has different syntax to what you might expect really, and I'm not 100% on the difference between IS and EQ off the top of my head.
3. You've already declared VAR x=2, so you don't need to define the variable again - a strict JavaScript engine might throw an error at that. It's already defined, so just set the value for it.
4. As mentioned, you're missing a semi-colon on the end of your CF injected line.

The code you should get rendered out would be:

```
<script> 
    var x = 2;
    x = 5;
</script>
```

Aside from that it's valid what you're trying to do. I often have a CF > JavaScript 'bridge' in my work - so long as you understand that one is run at compile time, before the page is passed to the web server and the other runs on the client machine at runtime.